# How to resize image from Uri?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget

I'm retrieving an image from a URI and displaying it in an Imageview.

I need to re-size the image from the URI to fit the size of the Imageview.

Please help me. How I can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
imageViewObject.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
```

Or, if you are configuring the `ImageView` from the XML file, you can use this property:

```
android:scaleType="centerInside"
```

Comment: Hi,
I tried scaletype "fitXY". Worked for me.
Thanks for reply